# Multithreading in Java and Native C on Android

Tags: java, android, c++, multithreading, native

I'm trying to separate native procesing from the whole app. I have one executor, and all requests to native part are processed as separate runnable instances on executor's thread. But always if the executor is processing something, I cannot interact with the app..

Is there any reason, why native processing thread cannot be swapped?

I have also changed the priority of the thread - to the lowest, but without changes. (the native part of code works about 1.5 second)

Comment: If you can't interact with the app, then something is running on the main UI thread, or the main UI thread is blocked waiting for another thread to complete. Get a thread dump with a debugger or DDMS when the app is non-interactive to see what's going on.

Comment: I think, there is nothing others, but I will check again